# JavaScript Concat

Tags: javascript

Via jquery / Javascript

Given a number 1234567891234

How can I concat, or truncast By removing the 2 from the left to make that number a valid integer I can insert into MySQL:'

4567891234

Thanks

---

This question edited by someone other than the OP, who's trying to guess at what the OP wants. Bear this in mind, but I *think* he wants to know:

How can I remove the first two characters from a string, using jQuery?

Comment: What on earth do you mean?

Comment: @SLaks I'm reading it out loud to see if that helps

Comment: Why do you have JavaScript formatting input to MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they want a substring of the original number:

```
var result = String(1234567891234).substr(2);
console.log(result); // Should be 34567891234
```

Answer (score 1):

A crossbrowser way:

(1234567891234).toString().slice(2);